# Gains in running a docker container on the same OS type?

Tags: docker

Are there significant gains in running a docker container based on a certain OS, on the same OS type and version?! For example, running a container based on a certain version of Ubuntu, on an Ubuntu server (of the same version), v.s. a Debian/CentOS/CoreOS server?

Notwithstanding, that upgrading the servers' and containers' OS in lockstep, might not be how ops always tend to go on in reality.

Comment: this is certainly not a question about programming, You would be better off posting it e.g. on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: done. http://serverfault.com/questions/758807/gains-in-running-a-docker-container-on-the-same-os-type

Comment: Cool. I will follow that one ;)